# Filter Through Radio Buttons - 2 sets of Data

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

I'm absolutely stumped and a complete newbie to Angular.  I've been scouring the internet for solutions, but I'm not sure what the right way is to do this...

Basically, I have to build a coffee shop ordering cart.  EG:
1) Select radio button 'Tea'.
2) And then show another row of radio buttons, with extras you can select.  EG 'Honey'.

I've got two sets of data, linked to my controller...

This row pulls through the options of Drinks, EG name: 'Latte'. price: 1.00.

Select a drink:

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="radio" ng-repeat="drink in grindsIndex.menuDrinks" >
    <input id='drinkRadio' type="radio" ng-model="value" value="{{ drink.price }}" placeholder="{{ drink.name }}" name="name" ng-model="grindsIndex.name" ng-change="drinkValue(value)" ng-click="clickMethod()"; [checked]="idx === 0"/>{{ drink.name }}
    </label>
</div>
```

When you click on one of the above, a new set of radio buttons appear, looping through a new set of data/extras.  Eg: name: 'Honey. price: 0.50p.

```
<div class="field" class="pricing-levels-3" ng-show="show">
    <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="extra in grindsIndex.menuExtras" >
    <input id='extrasOptions' class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="value" value="{{ extra.price }}" placeholder="{{ extra.name }}" name="name" ng-change='extraValue(value)'/ ng-true-value="{{ extra.price }}">{{ extra.name }}
    </label>
</div>
```

What I can't figure out is, if the user clicks 'Tea', how can I filter through the set of second radio buttons, to only show, say 'Honey', 'Milk' and 'Extra Shot'?

In total, I have 7 extras, but I need some kind of onClick, to only return a certain number of data key/pairs...

I just can't figure out the right approach. Any help would be grand...

Here's a snapshot of data as an example.

Drinks data:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'latte',
    price: 2.50,
},
{
   id: 2,
    name: 'capuccino',
    price: 2.50
},
```

Extras Data:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Extra Shot',
    price: 1.00
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Chocolate',
    price: 0.50
},
```

I've seen loads of different ways, even pushing the data through tables, but I'm just not sure, which way to go...

Comment: Try to add another property for your extras data as a group key/header.
For example extras _data: [ { id: 1, name: 'Honey', price: 1.00 , 'group': tea},{ id: 2, name: 'Chocolate', price: 0.50 ,group: 'latte'},  { id: 1, name: 'Extra Shot', price: 1.00 ,group: 'tea'}];

then you can use javascript filter, to filter your array based on the what is selected. [filter it using the "group" property]

Comment: if you've specified a the group property, try this:
var result = extras_data.filter(extra => extra.group === 'tea');
should return the data group only by tea.

Comment: Thank you Edwin!  I'm going to give this a go now!

Comment: where would i put this line of code Edwin?

    var result = extras_data.filter(extra => extra.group === 'tea');

Comment: Please read the tag description before adding them. [tag:filtering] and [tag:radio] are totally unrelated to the question!

Comment: ng-change="drinkValue(value)", inside drinkValue function,

drinkValue(value) {
   this.grindsIndex.menuExtras = this.grindsIndex.menuExtras.filter(extra => extra.group === value)
}